# Android database creation issue

Tags: android, sqlite

In my android application i'm using a manually created sqlite database.It works fine.Now i want to create a another temporary sqlite database by the application not manually.For that i created another Database helper class.Following is the code.But that databse is not creating.I checked the DDMS file explorer to verify the database.But it shows only my manually created database.

```
package com.buddhi.app;

import android.content.Context;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;
import android.util.Log;

public class TempDatabaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper{

private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;
private static final String USER_INPUT_TABLE = "user_input";
private static String DATABASE_NAME = "temp_db.sqlite";

private static final String USER_INPUT_TABLE_CREATE =
            "CREATE TABLE " + USER_INPUT_TABLE + " (" +
                    "_id" + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, " +
                    "input" + " TEXT);";

TempDatabaseHelper(Context context) {
    super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
}

@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
    db.execSQL(USER_INPUT_TABLE_CREATE);
}

@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
    Log.w("","Drop table...");
        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + USER_INPUT_TABLE);
        onCreate(db);
}

}
```

Comment: Where your are searching for? temp_db.sqlite is in /data/data/yourPackageName/databases/temp_db.sqlite.

Comment: Make sure you are calling `getReadableDatabase()` or `getWriteableDatabase()`, because db is initialized lazily. Also, compare versions before dropping tables in upgrade.

Comment: can you show us code where `TempDatabaseHelper` is used?

Comment: Thanks everyone for commenting on my question:)@MisaghEmamverdi:yeas i was checked there.

Comment: @S.D.:OK i'll check that.

Comment: @k3b:This is the code that i have used.

TempDatabaseHelper tempDbHelper=new TempDatabaseHelper(null);

And i'm getting a "Application has unexpectedly closed" message when i click the start button of the application

Comment: @S.D.:Yes i tried the way that you have mentioned.Still it's not working.

Comment: HI finally i could solve the issue.This is the working code part.I think this is the way @S.D. mentioned.Anyhow finally it's working.

SQLiteDatabase tempdb=new TempDatabaseHelper(this).getWritableDatabase();